Preposition "On' | "At" | "Upon"
Upon my request, he played my favorite song
On my request, he played my favorite song
At my request, he played my favorite song
I have seen these kind of sentences several times. Are there any differences in meaning with use of upon/on or at in these kind of sentences?

Hi! Please edit to show what you've already found out about these usages, so we can talk about whether your sources are misleading or have just been misunderstood. I think you've combined some usages: "on/upon request" and "at my request." They're similar but not totally compatible. Voting to close for now as needing more explanation.

There's no difference in meaning, except that any preposition other than at might be seen as evidence of a poor writer (or maybe non-native Anglophone)...


The differences are subtle and these are probably interchangeable in practice.
"At my request" means, specifically, in reponse to my request. The emphasis is that there is a causal link.
"On" / "upon" both mean following my request, although the implication is that there is also a causal link.
